# Adjusting the elements css elements with bootstrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In my header I have added three elemets. Arrow, fb icon , twitter icon.

Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/2qSSW/1/)

Html:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="email-input navbar-left">
        <div id="error-msg" class="help-block">             
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">
                    Login
                    <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i>
                </p>
            </div>
```

Problem with this is `Login` text and `Arrow (>)` dont aligns in middle of header.

I tried changing their top-bottom margin and padding but no change.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class in css:

```
.text {
        float: left;
        margin: 4px;
    }
```

then wrap your login text with arrow like this:

```
<span class="a">Login <i class="fa fa-play"></i></span>
```

Comment: But I have used text at various elements in my page, this will affect to all those elements also na?

Comment: well I got clue from this, just changes class name to someother .. thanks